# How do I figure out how much a share is worth in the PPLNS world?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, block-reward, hash-verification, difficulty-share

I'm trying to figure out how much accepted shares are worth, however small, in a mining pool, situation, specifically of a PPLNS scheme.  What is the formula to figure how what a specific share is worth?  I thought block reward might come into play, but since PPLNS isn't bounded by found blocks, I'm somewhat confused about how to start calculating.  I'm mining in this pool -- https://mixpools.org/xmr/ but use whatever pool as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Shares are not equal. One persons "share" may have X difficulty and anthers has Y difficulty. Each share is associated the difficulty of an accepted hash. PPLNS favors miners that stay on one pool (as opposed to pool hopping) because the percentage of a found block payout is not just splitting on the hashes submitted for that particular block.

A good explanation of a specific implementation of PPLNS can be found [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=39832).